# MFC: how CListBox sets the number of columns when multi-column is selected?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am studying this code https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796/Using-the-CListBox-control. What puzzles me is that it has a "Multi column" list which shows 5 columns when the program is running but I don't seem to find where the number of columns is specified. It only uses AddString(...) and is 5 columns a default?

Comment: The number of columns most likely depends on the number of items you added to that listbox

Comment: A multi-column list-box is a list-box that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically, rather than a control like listview, which does have true columns. The "columns" here are just the "items", scrolled vertically, so yes, `AddString()` adds a new "column". Columns can be displayed by using tabs (and the `LBS_USETABSTOPS` style and possibly the `LB_SETTABSTOPS` message or the `CListBox::SetTabStops()` function), or as mentioned above a listview control instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, it is not true column, and the number of columns depends on the number of items added and the height of the box. It tries to add as many items as possible to one column until the height, then moves on to the next column.